# How can I run away while engaged in a sword fight?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I find myself getting locked in combat with a group of enemies and unable to run and hide easily or at all and end up button mashing my controller attempting to get my assassin to run away. It is incredibly frustrating since I have always been able to run away while engaging in combat in previous assassin's creed games.

Any advice on how to get my assassin to quickly remove himself from his combat stance and run away?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would think that turning your back on and then running from a sword wielding enemy might be a bad idea if you value your health.  But I've never played any of the AC games, so take my comment with a grain of salt.

Comment: lol thats the problem im having it wont let me turn away from my enemy to run. (you get smoke bombs/cherry bombs that distract the enemy so you can run)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your system, press what ever button you use to lock on(LT/L1/F for 360/PS3/PC) to break the lock on, and sprint in the opposite direction of your enemy.  Then it's just the standard run far enough away or hide so that you become anonymous again.

I have noticed that in this game it is harder than others to escape combat.  I seem to remember just being able to press the buttons to sprint in the opposite direction to break combat and start running.

Comment: *sigh* i couldve sworn i tried this but apparantly i didnt cause as soon as i did it, it worked....