# How do I de-lock away from enemies?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I'm fairly new to the Assassins Creed series, and one thing that's been bugging me like crazy is locking on to enemies.  Sometimes, when I'm running away from guards, I end up accidently locking on to one of them, making me unable to run around at my leisure.

How do I get rid of lock on?

Comment: Just press the same button. On x360, you press RT to lock on an enemy and the same button to unlock IIRC.

Comment: So, if I press e again, I'll instantly de-lock from enemies?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, and it frequently does not workk.  Sometimes, if I smash the spacebar repeatedly, it will delock, but sometimes it wont.

Comment: As I'm assuming you are playing this on the PC, have you checked your keybind settings. That would be the easiest way to find out if your target lock-on/lock-off keys are the same. If they aren't then problem solved. If they are, then try changing them. There may in all honesty be a button combination you have to press to lock-off a target, like "ctrl + e".

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59952/how-can-i-run-away-while-engaged-in-a-sword-fight/59962#59962 (pretty sure the combat system doesn't change much between 2/BH/Revelations)

Comment: @turbo - The underline system didn't change but AC2 combat was very different then `BH` and `Revelations`.

Comment: I remember on Xbox it was pretty similar, press LT to lock on, press LT again to unlock and RT + stick in the opposite direction to run away.

Comment: sometimes RT + stick in the opposite direction to run away doesn't work. I hat the dudes on horseback that i can't lock off of. I did RT + A + stick direction and it worked.